# How to find a p-value less than 0.05 from a given dataset in R

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have a list of raw p-values from an experiment. I need to find the p-values less than 0.05 from that dataset and then adjust using certain methods. How I can find the p-values less than 0.05 in R. There are 4 columns in my dataset. The p-values are on the 4th column.

Comment: Surely you mean you need to adjust the p-values and *then* find the ones less than 0.05. Doing it the other way will wildly underestimate the number of hypotheses you actually tested and give you far too liberal a correction factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would adjust your p values first before getting the significant ones. You can use different methods depending upon how stringent you want the multiple comparisons to be accounted for ( Bonferroni being the most I think).

```
    ##df being your data with four columns, the p values in the 4th. 
    pvalues <- df[, 4]
    padjust<- p.adjust(pvalues, method="fdr")

    ##this will give you the row numbers of the sig p adjusted values 
    padjustsig<- which(padjust < 0.05)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!